# Adding a SearchBar method

Tags: iphone, objective-c

When we add some text to the `uisearchbar`, we see a cross on the right hand side of it. When we click on this, the text in the `uisearchbar` gets cleared.  Here's an [image](http://www.mediabistro.com/alltwitter/files/2010/02/tweetie_5.png) that shows the cross.

What i need to do is, i need to know how the event that would respond to this cross (when clicked).

When the user clicks on this cross, i need to print a `NSLog(@"Cross clicked");`

How can i do this programatically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking in the `UISearchBarDelegate` documentation:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText // called when text changes (including clear)
```

Comment: I want to shoot an event when the user clicks on the `X` close button on the uisearchBar. `textDidChange` isn't the method.

Answer (score 0):

Use the UISearchbarDelegate-Protocol in your UIViewController. There is a method that would called.

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UISearchBarDelegate

Comment: I want to shoot an event when the user clicks on the X close button on the uisearchBar. textDidChange isn't the method.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do a different action with the clear button .. you could build a custom one instead the default one and implement any event when click it.

```
    UISearchBar *searchBar = yourSearchBar;
UITextField *searchtextfield = [searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:1];
UIButton *cButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
cButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20 , 20);
cButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[cButton setImage:[UIImage newImageFromResource:@"yourButtonImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//If you want like the x button put image similar to it.
cButton.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
[cButton addTarget:self action:@selector(clearButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];//This is the custom event
[searchtextfield setRightView:cButton];
[searchtextfield setRightViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
```

Comment: If you look at the image that i have linked in my question, you will see a CLOSE button represented with a `X` in the searchbar. I need to print a NSLog when the user clicks on it.

Comment: yeah i see .. this is button called clear button .. its built in button from the iOS .. you cant make custom event through it until you replace it with a custom button .. if you are intrested i will show you how.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be notified when the user clicks the "x" button, implement the protocol that previous users have suggested, and add this implementation:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    if ([searchText isEqualToString:@""]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", @"clear button pressed");
    }
}
```

The only downside to this is that it's also called if the user backspaces to a blank search field. You would need to find some way to determine if the backspace was the most recent keypress, potentially by checking the location of the last `UITouch` against the known location of the backspace key.

Comment: you are checking for `[searchText isEqualToString:@""]`, but `searchText ` is what the user types in the textbox. this is not a `X` button click as shown in the image in the question

Comment: yes, but whenever the `x` button is clicked, it clears the text and fires the `textDidChange` method. this is not an ideal solution, it's more of a workaround